# git clone authentication failed when AD auth changed

Tags: git, azure-devops, active-directory, samba, rhel7

Recently we changed the authentication method at the backend for AD as **NTLM V2** in the **Samba auth** methods and while this was changed, though the server login and other login methods to **RHEL7** machine worked correctly, we were unable to authenticate while performing a git clone to code repo in **AzureDevOps**.

The issue was identified that the **NTLM V1** version in the **Samba auth** method is supported for the **RHEL7** servers which we use and later rolling back the version from **V2 to V1**, we were able to authenticate the git clone.

Can anyone let me know if you ever faced this kind of authentication issues with NTLM V2 and how it was fixed? or is there any other auth methods with which we can do the git clone to RHEL7 machines by having NTLM V2 for Samba auth at the AD level.

Comment: Can you share authentication error details with us?

Comment: [test@test123 ~]$ git clone https://azuredevops.com/devops/Digital/_git/Ansible_repo
Cloning into 'Ansible_repo'...
Username for 'https://azuredevops.com': test
Password for 'https://test@azuredevops.com':
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://azuredevops.com/Digital/Ansible_repo'
--

Comment: No additional info coming up at our end while trying to do the git clone

Comment: Have you tried to set the **auth = yes** in the smb.conf file and check if it can work?

Comment: lanman auth = no
   client use spnego = no
   client ntlmv2 auth = yes
   client lanman auth = no
   ntlm auth = yes
==
tried with the above but still its the same.